# Increase edge binding delay?

Tags: compiz

Is it possible to increase the delay on the edge bindings in CCSM? I would like to have the Activity Journal launch if I hold my mouse in the lower right corner, but I find myself accidently launching it all the time if I just pass by the corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the *General Options plugin* options, there's a delay setting for the edge triggering (*Edge Trigger Delay*):

[image]